# How to make a dockingport not detatch it self?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

Actually I'm experimenting with dockingports because before I sent a spacecraft into orbit which later should be dockable, I'm experimenting I got it correct how the ports are working.

Fortunately I did so...

Actually my problem is, I have a scenario where 2 spacecrafts are docking each other on the launchway. but after I click to detatch, the port detatches from the counterpart as expectet, but.... it also detatches itself from the spacecraft...

### This is a screenshot of the current testing setup:

[image: TestingScenario]

---

http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Docking#Docking_ports

is telling this is a mistake often done by beginners, but doesn't tell how to avoid this / do it correctly.

So my question simply is, how to dock correctly, in a way detatching just detatches the ports from each other but none of both from any spacecraft part?

Comment: Are you sure you put them the right way around? The more detailed side is supposed to be outside.

Comment: @Philipp: I'm going to upload a screenshot

Comment: @Philipp: screenshot for clarification is added.

Comment: Pretty sure your only problem is that you're using _detach_ instead of _undock_.  The option to undock may only be on one of the two ports.  However, it's been too long since I last played for me to post this as an answer and be confident that it's correct.

Comment: Can you post another screenshot of just after the undocking which shows which piece is disconnected from your ship? I can't get a feel of what you're explaining because I can't visualize it.

Comment: @TimS.: Can't reproduce it anymore. seems to have been a bug. without any change in the craft it just started working as expected at one point. What was happening is: When you see the screenshot, the testing construction was designed to in one stage lower the uper part so the dockingport controllable snaps and they get connected. but when I then clciked "detatch" the port just undocked (what was fine) BUT ALSO just dropped of from the upper part so there was a seperated depris consisting of a single dockingport entity. while the upper part of the spacecraft had no port atached anymore at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your response to my comment, this is almost definitely a bug. Perhaps you saved/exited/reloaded the game fixed it? I've had cases where after assembly, a ship will act in a non-expected way, but after saving and reloading the game, it never happens again. It did always have to do with attachment points though.

Since you can't reproduce it and don't already have a screenshot, I'd not recommend submitting a bug with the devs, just be happy it's not doing it anymore.

Answer (score -1):

A docking port has an "outside" (the side that attaches and detaches) and an "inside" (the side that stays attached) face.  In your screenshot, the two outside faces are mated together correctly.  This means that you can undock and then dock again without issue.

The common mistakes made are:

- Putting a docking port on backwards so that the outside face (that
  will disconnect) is attached to there you want your docking port to
  remain.  Just pay attention to the part, it's usually pretty clear
  which side is which, and a experimentation on the launch pad will
  quickly identify it if you are in doubt.
- Using two docking ports when you only need one.  A docking port can
  be assembled with any other part "docked" to it.  The only things
  docking ports are good for are:

  - Disconnecting two parts (one port needed)
  - Joining two parts once launched (two ports needed).

Comment: I don't think you understand the question being asked.  Your answer is just saying what is supposed to happen, but doesn't address what is actually happening.